# Hermatic testing for BLE based Android application

Tags: android, mocking, android-testing, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm having a problem in testing BLE-based android application. To perform test I have to highly depend on the BLE device. Which is slowing down the overall development time and creating the flaky test.

I searched on google to find any example to perform Hermetic testing of a BLE-based  application. But no success till yet.

Is there any good solution for this problem? Is there any mocking library for BLE?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which library you are using for BLE. I'm using [this](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle) one which enables mocking of BLE objects. See https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle#unit-tests